# Typescript - What is the best way to type check an object properties and throw upon null?

Tags: typescript, object, null, throw

Suppose that we have this Typescript code, what could be the best way to code the TODO part ? My team and I are looking for an elegant way to do that

```
type MyType = {
  key1?: string | null
  key2?: string | null
  key3?: string | null
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
};

type MyTypeNotNull = {
  key1?: string
  key2?: string
  key3?: string
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
};

function logMyType(type: MyTypeNotNull) {
  console.log(type);
}

const myType: MyType = {
  key1: 'myKey1',
  // key2 is omitted
  key3: null,
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
};

const run = (value: MyType) => {
  /* TODO
    - throw when a prop is null
    - make myType pass the type check of logMyType
  */

  logMyType(value); // Error Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'
};

run(myType);
```

Currently we have a bunch of **if** following each other, and feel that it should exist a better way to do that, do you have any clean suggestions ?

Comment: You could write an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nrn01N); does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it's matching what I needed. Thanks for your quick response !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that iterates over all its argument's properties and throws if any of them are `null`; and the returned assertion predicate (of the form `asserts xxx is YYY`) would [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of the argument to a version with all non-null properties.  Here's one approach:

```
function assertNoPropsAreNull<T extends object>(obj: T): asserts obj is
    { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], null> } {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v === null)
            throw new Error("OH NOEZ, PROP \"" + k + "\" IS NULL");
    });
}
```

The implementation of `assertNoPropsAreNull()` uses [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key/value pairs for the `arg` argument, and throws an error if it finds any where the value is null (and mentions the key in the error message).

The call signature of `assertNoPropsAreNull()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of `obj`, and the return type is `asserts obj is { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], null> }`.  That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which just strips `null` out of each property type via [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).

Let's test it:

```
const run = (value: MyType) => {

  value; // (parameter) value: MyType

  assertNoPropsAreNull(value)
  value; /* (parameter) value: {
    key1?: string | undefined;
    key2?: string | undefined;
    key3?: string | undefined;
  } */

  logMyType(value); // okay    
};
```

The compiler behavior looks good.  Before calling `assertNoPropsAreNull(value)`, the type of `value` is `MyType`, and afterwards it has been narrowed to `{key1?: string, key2?: string, key3?: string}`.  This type is [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) identical to your `MyTypeNotNull` type, and thus `logMyType()` accepts it with no warnings.

And let's make sure the runtime behavior is also acceptable:

```
run({ key1: 'myKey1' }); // {key1: "myKey1"}

run({ key1: 'myKey1', key3: null }); //  OH NOEZ, PROP "key3" IS NULL
```

That also looks good.  In the first case the assertion succeeds and so `logMyType()` is called with a `MyTypeNotNull`-compatible input, while in the second case the assertion fails and `logMyType()` is not called at all.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4#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-k0OFo4tq3t8yFQb3aRmDOGALsRAHd2BBUzLqIjqLUAET6gASUFc+plAC0NXCAEr6uFQAA6udzUAA1HhW1Bc42oABJADKxYAqgAZYe58ZGKwTyYYaazaj5XxQcNgxWNZw1CD+wNGb2rjgQGzGZdgMHUMFzCB3aidPdr5aboxs6GwhFI1HozErtexzR3g9HloABUJ5nheV7Qre+7rkG6xEIoUQSFA+TKjkDAPHY8bhAhCSqChEBofQGFxngsQ4eIeHEgR6H3JhOC6kBWhGMMzR1P+W6Abo7i4GCIAYACC70LUfKBNsewHDq4zHmgomduJRC5jOgnCaRRBiSA+xEEcqkvJqXCSZxUCALwbgClO1AhbFqWFZQNWtadvIzb9kOo5AA)