# Typescript assert function to avoid Non-Null Assertion Operator ! with Objects

Tags: typescript, assertion

based on this post [Typescript - What is the best way to type check an object properties and throw upon null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237470/typescript-what-is-the-best-way-to-type-check-an-object-properties-and-throw-u/73238135#73238135)

I'm trying to check if values of my object are not undefined and narrow the type of the argument to a version with all non-null properties but I keep having this issue: "Argument of type '{ Id?: string | undefined; Name?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyTypeNotNull'."

I would like to know what's wrong with my assert function signature ?

```js
type MyType = {
    Id?: string | undefined
    Name?: string | undefined
};

type MyTypeNotNull = {
    Id: string
    Name: string
};

function logMyType(type: MyTypeNotNull) {
    console.log(type);
}

function assertNoPropsAreUndefined<T extends object>(obj: T): asserts obj is
    { [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]> } {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        console.log(k, v)
        if (v === undefined)
            throw new Error("OH NOEZ, PROP \"" + k + "\" IS NULL");
    });
}

const run = (value: MyType) => {
    value; // (parameter) value: MyType
    assertNoPropsAreUndefined(value)
    value;
    logMyType(value); // should be ok but it throw Argument of type '{ Id?: string | undefined; Name?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyTypeNotNull'.
};

run({ Id: 'myKey1', Name: "ok" }); // {key1: "myKey1"}

run({ Id: 'myKey1', Name: undefined }); //  OH NOEZ, PROP "key3" IS NULL
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQJIBMB%20ALigGdgAnASwDsBzKAHygFdb8IAzOifLHADkAhgFsIJclTqMW7Tj1p8MAXwDcGDKEiwESQQHtgg1gBtTUVJhx58pCjQYDsI8felP1mruwDGwagNaKFMDejhESAAKbQhSCP0jE3MASnRnKF8gsgNTCAA6UPoYpBSNFW8-AKCoYTIyCEpjAwAFSgMwMgBBSggAVQ5uXnwAHngoCAAPYAgOMigDACMAKwh-AD4opeXSeBTSOoam%20e2oajIMtCgAbQBpM%20CAawgQAy4oeABdUkNaZNNhIs8mM7p91lAVOkbAB5FZrYD5WbSCBkLYrFL5LgGSgAUWEvgAFlEotdHgAaKAAN0%20aWQ4OsNhwWVoOTyhTCUXJVJSGRs1HeUUplmQqHkQyU%20B5jOlUGABPaAHcoEolTjKO1KFEAETQgASUEE0JxAC0KS0AErQlpQAA6Wq1UAA1FBHk6oFq7XgAMoGvoAGT9WrKGRUwYqGGZFCglHYligguEplYcV0kQgtPpGUpieTaigAHp8-GwMJKGIIDNKGls0mUwlIBlDo1mm0Ot1egMFMME7WpTga7mMkV6xAe8mygWi2QCQYzPgoItoAZXYtWMAzuu5YqoD16KxxLR129ZUgoAByK4ESQOGTMNiDRR8POuCTuRyye9diV5lRns7zWgjFqepqHoWhATyWUDCgEsy3ESsFneWJzxHQxjDMUwz3yVQNAwGNaCiS87HPUQQFuF4AEYzwpF9SC1ZcHVDPNC3QZ4QAoujSPI9itXDfDCNsUgzy4yjqINctSDFR95yYycoEAXg3AFKdqA9QNI1TSgC0rXdNiAGYHVwH1BH9P0gA)

Comment: `NonNullable` means it's not nullable. It doesn't mean that an optional property becomes mandatory.

Comment: [`Required` built-in type](https://tsplay.dev/mMB1rW)

Comment: "OH NOEZ" looked strangely familiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @caTS. For others in the same situation I was missing the Required built-in type.

```js
type MyType = {
    Id?: string | undefined
    Name?: string | undefined
};

type MyTypeNotNull = {
    Id: string
    Name: string
};

function logMyType(type: MyTypeNotNull) {
    console.log(type);
}

function assertNoPropsAreUndefined<T extends object>(obj: T): asserts obj is
    Required<{ [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]> }> {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v === undefined)
            throw new Error("OH NOEZ, PROP \"" + k + "\" IS NULL");
    });
}

const run = (value: MyType) => {
    value; // (parameter) value: MyType
    assertNoPropsAreUndefined(value)
    value;
    logMyType(value);
};

run({ Id: 'myKey1', Name: "ok" }); // {key1: "myKey1"}

run({ Id: 'myKey1', Name: undefined }); //  OH NOEZ, PROP "Name" IS NULL
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKuoEkATAfgC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcygB8oBXewiAMwYkLY8UAHIBDALYQylGg2ZtO3PvQHYAvgG5s2UJFgIkIgPbAR7ADYWoqTDjxFyVOkyF5xUp3NdYtOrDycAMbAtMb0UBbGjHCIkAAUehDksUam5lYAlOhuuEHhFMYWEAB0UYyJSJnavv6B9CFhEWIUFBDUZsYACtTGYBQAgtQQAKpcvPyEADzwUBAAHsAQXBRQxgBGAFYQIQB88Rub5PCZ5C1tHauHULQUuVAAShAAjuy0w9NoUADaANI3EQA1hAQMYeFB4ABdcgmegZCxidbFGZ-SG7KDqdF2YQAeS2O2AJWWcggFAOW0yJR4xmoAFExEEABbxeLfQEAGigADdIdlkFj7sJaOD4lybMhUEoJqpCJlBcI8MBGb0AO5QVRq2nUXrUeIAIhxAAlRDjaQAtTldB44rpQAA6er1UAA1FBAS6oHqHQQAMqiEYAGQDeuq93UodqWGw%20XoVCg1E4NigorEFnYyQMcQgfIF9lwXNT6c0UAA9CXk2AxNRJBAltRsgW0xnUpB7ud2p0en1BsMxspJimm3K89zCxAasJyi2IIP0xG-FGsAn6PEvo4oAByCQgX4ggCMG85HgzeuMgKd4eLZfQwJAe-Ieu3u7vevU-mXq4IhHIW53%208Pog1uQUoqAIGLVKW5aALwbgClO1ARomualrWraeq3gAzE6%20B%20iIgYBkAA)

Comment: `Required<{ [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]> }>` is excessive, you just need `Required<T>`

Comment: @VLAZ Then `null` would pass through. I'm not sure if they intended for `null` to also be excluded but that is what `NonNullable` does.

Comment: @caTS ah, I missed that `null` wasn't needed. I was just going off `MyType`. In that case, it would be shorter to use `{ [K in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[K]> }` (the extra `-?` to make properties not optional) than `Required`. Not much difference in bytes but it's an option.

Comment: I prefer to use Required instead of -? in term of readability.
Thanks guys, I learned new things today